# Looping over elements with values gives value is not defined

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Once page load is completed, I am looking for table cells which contain elements (number input fields) with an id of "check_status". I then loop over them (example simplified to a console.log).

**Coffeescript**

```
ready = ->
  $('td').find('#check_status').each (i, el) =>
    console.log el.val()
  return

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <div>
        <input type="number" value="1" name="check[status]" id="check_status">
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <input type="number" value="0" name="check[status]" id="check_status">
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <input type="number" value="2" name="check[status]" id="check_status">
    </div>
</td>
```

Console.log of $('td').find('#check_status') gives me all the elements I am looking for, but console.log of el.val() gives "el is not defined". Why?

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context...

Comment: And `el` is DOM node, not jq object. Use `el.value` or `$(el).val();` or use `this` but not `el.val()`.

Comment: `"el is not defined"` Which browser gives you this error, because that's not the case. `el` is defined but `val` property isn't

Comment: Chrome. Thanks, I'd overlooked the unique IDs entirely. I'm using Rails and these duplicate IDs are because every input field is generated in a separate form_for. I will add some unique identifier to the IDs, then return to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit ended up being this (snippet from [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)):

```
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);

ready = ->
    ... function contents ...
```

Not quite sure why that made the each in the ready function fail, but it works fine when I instead use:

```
$(document).ready ->
    ... function contents ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Id's should be unique. You should change `id="check_status"` to `class="check_status"` and the selection to `find('.check_status')`.

Comment: That's true but that's not related to issue here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **.each()** with a **function** inside?
Like this:

```
$('td').find('#check_status').each (function (i, el){
  console.log (el.val())
});
```

Comment: Still `el` is a DOM node. FYI, OP is already using each loop, using coffescript syntax

Comment: So, maybe, instead of `el` he could use `$(this).val()`